# Copy Parallel editor tool - python script / modelbuilder

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, parallel-lines

Is it possible to use Copy Parallel tool in a python script or in modelbuilder for ArcGIS 10.2? Does anyone have a workaround or script for a tool that essential does the same thing as Copy Parallel. I have a modelbuilder model that needs to copy parallel lines from a street centerline shapefile, buffering will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think "Copy Parallel" is accesible via ArcPy or Model-Builder, using ArcObjects is a possibility.

A possible work around would be to buffer your line features, then use the "Feature to Line" tool.

Comment: thanks for the response. In this case using the buffer and feature to line tools don't get me the result I need.

Comment: This post has detailed steps to replicate Copy Parallel. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25739/how-to-create-an-offset-polyline-in-arcpy